# Undesired result with C# modulus operator

Tags: c#, .net

I was trying a simple exercise that shows on the screen all of the numbers that are multiples of 3 or 5 between 1-1000. As everyone knows the way to find this is using the modulus operator(%) and, if the modulus division returns 0 the number is multiple of 3 or 5, whatever you're comparing, very simple.

The point is that for some reason when I compare the expression `if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)`  the first number that matches is 363.

When I compare only with 3  `if (i % 3 == 0)`  the first number that matches is 105, and finally when I compare with only 5 if (i % 5 == 0) the result is as expected, starting from 5.

I would like to know what's going on here, or is just something so simple that I can't see at this time of the night due to I'm falling asleep.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long total = 0;


        for (int i = 3; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                total += i;
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

            }

        }

        Console.Read();

    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly on my system.

Comment: like @Selman22 said, it's my console, it has a limitation with the size

Comment: Actually, I am using `mono` on Ubuntu, so I just piped the output to `less`. You should get UnixUtils and play with them on Windows. :)

Comment: i like linux a lot, now i'm studying CS but I studied a lot of network management before, especially linux(debian, ubuntu) but for .net, VS is the way to go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it always displaying the correct result but you can't see them because of your Console size.

Try:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    if (i % 100 == 0) Console.Read();
}
```

Press enter to see next `100` numbers.

Comment: @fernando, It will show exactly as many as your screen height. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting your output to a file and looking at it. Use `Program.exe > Output.txt` to redirect and then open it in Notepad.

Comment: holly molly, you were right, the txt file was ok, I almost got crazy, thanks. Well I learned something else, the console is pretty tiny dough.